# Swift JSON from POST request

Tags: json, swift, http, post, request

I struggle with Swift and I never had any experience with it. When I do POST request with text/string body to my api, I receive back JSON data, but I don't know how to extract that data from JSON to Swift. I tried writing the Codable but I was unsuccessful.

```
func loginCall() {
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.0.50/api/v1/?op=ilogin") else {
        return
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let body = "email=myemail@gmail.com&password=jdsdsdsdf&ver=0.1";
    
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        
        if error == nil && data != nil {
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            
            do {
                let loginDetailsJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                print(loginDetailsJSON)
                
            }
            catch
            {
                print("Error JSON")
            }
            
            
        }
        
    }
    dataTask.resume()
    
}
```

The response from my api

```
{"error":false,"data":{"name":"Test Name","age":18,"active":true},"message":"LOGIN: Success!"}
```

My Codable

```
struct LoginUser: Codable
{
    var error:Bool?
    var data:[LoginUserData]?
    var message:String?
    
}

struct LoginUserData: Codable
{
    var name:String
    var age:Int
    var active:Bool?
    
}
```

Whenever I try to decode it with my Codable I get error and the app crashes... I need to save any data from API to/in my app.

Comment: It's hard to know what's going on without more information. Add an else clause to your `if error == nil` and log the error you're getting.

Comment: As from your API response, ``data`` only has 1 ``LoginUserData`` so try remove array then ``var data:LoginUserData?``

Comment: Also, your body looks more like query parameters than body data (the `key=value,&key=value` syntax exactly matches query parameters that are appended to the URL.) Are you sure your POST request wants that as the body of the POST?

Comment: bewithyou - Indeed that was the issue! Thank you so much!